# Number of Subparvas in Neelkanth and Critical edition of Mahabharat?

Tags: mahabharata

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahabharata) tells there are about 100 sub-parvas in Mahabharat.
But It is unclear if it is talking about Crtical or Neelkanth edition.

I want to know how many sub-parvas are there in -

1. NeelKanth Edition
2. Critical Edition